# Something to avoid conflict while saving to database

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm planning to create a code that will save in my database. (I have no problem in saving to my database thou.)

But I'm having a bit problem. The problem is to avoid having the same seat information displayed for the specific customer.

Something like this? (Sorry for the sample data that I will be doing.) The case is both are doing their inputs for their reservation at the same time.

**`[X]`** = **taken data**, **`[0]`** = **blank data**, **`[R]`** = **customer data**

1st viewing customer (having 2 data to be stored)

```
[X][X][X][R][R]

[0][0][0][0][0]

[0][0][0][0][0]
```

2nd viewing customer (having 1 data to be stored, and must be showed for this customer)

```
[X][X][X][X][X]

[R][0][0][0][0]

[0][0][0][0][0]
```

What the 2nd viewing customer actually sees. Which the customer mustn't encounter. And so on if there are other more customers are doing their inputs.

```
[X][X][X][R][0]

[0][0][0][0][0]

[0][0][0][0][0]
```

My first tactical plan is to create two database tables, one database table will serve as a dummy and the other will serve as the main database table. The logic is the dummy table will always update if there are customers making their inputs (which will have a problem by the time the customer closes the browser or didn't finish the transaction, the data stored at the dummy will still remain even after other customer accessed it again - which must not happen). And the main table will only update when the customer completed the whole transaction.

I know from the way I typed it is a bit confusing. But I really need some help in creating a logic to avoid this conflict the customer will see in my program. Or some tips if this kind of plan will not work. Like giving a note that (same sample above with 1st and 2nd customer) "This data is just a sample and sometimes will not be followed or the same with the e-mail sent to your registered e-mail addressed from this website."

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think it's a good idea to save all clicks in final seat info table. Instead of that you can make something like temporary_seats base which will keep temporary information about reserved seats. In this table you would include information about seats that customers wishes to reserve.

Then you need to create javascript code querying API and getting all reserved (from destination table) and temporary reserved (from tmp table) and mark those seats free/occupied. You can do it constantly or check seat availability only when t

Comment: So you mean, I will create a javascript that will make those that are on the seats that are really occupied from the start will be marked occupied when retrieved (vice-versa for the free) and the temporary reserved will be marked as occupied/free? and you didn't finish your answer so I'm a bit confused for the full detail.

Comment: Strange :) What I was trying to say was you can do it in 2 different ways: 1) constantly ask api about seat reservation and mark it free/reserved when change. OR 2) set onClick method and then check with API this particular seat status

Comment: Temporary table allows you to manage the tmp reservation time. So seat won't be occupied forever but only during particular time period.